# What browsers support font: icon?

Tags: css, fonts

By a quirk of fate I support an application that uses "font: icon" for most of its "normal" text. For the uninitiated, "font: icon" gets your fonts in the same type and size as Windows uses for icon labels on the desktop etc.

I know for a fact that IE does support it, but not Chrome. I would imagine that it is not implemented on any of the Linux or Mac specific browsers either. Has anyone ever really checked what browsers actually support it?

[Chrome would ignore "font: icon" and fall back on the default font settings]

Comment: Weird. I had never even heard of this. My guess would be that IE on Windows is the only browser that supports this.

Comment: I hadn't either, until I started maintaining this app. The documentation on the topic is really scarce, and the CSS spec also mentions it in passing (as the implementation is up to the browser makers anyway). See the w3schools entry here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font.asp

Answer (score 0):

Firefox also supports it and it's not Windows specific..

It's mentioned as one of the system fonts in the MDN entry: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font

And according to http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116136 it seems that Safari also supports it.